# Accessing Tableview in splitViewController from AppDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have searched much but with no success. I am attempting to access the TableView of the splitViewController from AppDelegate.swift. How do I do this?

This is the standard code that Apple supplies when starting a new project for a Split View Controller:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
        let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
        navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
        splitViewController.delegate = self

        return true
    }
```

Or perhaps it is not possible? Which I cannot believe :-)

Comment: It's acually a bad approach. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to decouple the TableView from my data storage. Should result in more robust and maintainable code? But perhaps I am looking for a wrong solution?

Comment: You may store your data in a separate object, but it's better to set view controller as a table view's data source. `AppDelegate` is definitely a wrong place to do anything with `UITableView`

Comment: hi have you seen this post that is very good post of splitviewcontroller have look might be solve--:
http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/splitviewcontroller-in-iphone-using-swift